# Firefox directory

Tags: objective-c, firefox, path, directory, pathname

I have this code, and it's ok.

```
NSString *pathName = [@"/Users/" stringByAppendingString:NSUserName()];
        pathName = [pathName stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Configuration.plist"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pathName error:nil];
```

I want to use this directory, but there's a folder with **cbk4yc7r.default**.
cbk4yc7r change for each user. how can I modify the code to use this directory?

```
"/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/cbk4yc7r.default/places.sqlite"
```

I tried "/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/*.default/places.sqlite" but does not work in objective-c.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what cbk4yc7r is for each user, you can do:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/%@.default/places.sqlite", user.dirString];
```

where `user.dirstring` is the equivalent of cbk4yc7r for each user.

Comment: `user.dirstring` was just an example for a way that you might be accessing this string that is different for each user. This should be replaced by whatever variable you have handy (probably as a result of parsing profiles.ini as described by @valexa below).

Answer (score 0):

First off you should be using

```
NSString *pathName = [@"~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

to get the proper parent directory, secondly the profiles inside that directory are defined by the ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/profiles.ini file e.g. "Path=Profiles/cbk4yc7r.default" so you need to parse profiles.ini or use

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathName error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use some Firefox API (if it exists) to determine the profile IDs.  But I don't know Firefox internals well enough to know if this is feasible.  I *do* know that a single user can have multiple profiles, though, which is something to consider.

Also, you (and, frankly, the other responders) are making a lot of assumptions about directory structure that aren't guaranteed to hold.  You are also assuming that everything works correctly, which of course isn't guaranteed for disk operations.  With these considerations in mind, I submit the following which makes fairly thorough use of abstractions supplied by Foundation.  It also uses the more modern NSURL where appropriate:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *appDirErr;
    NSURL *appSupportDir = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                               inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                      appropriateForURL:nil
                                                 create:NO
                                                  error:&appDirErr];

    if (appSupportDir) {
        NSURL *firefoxDir = [appSupportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Firefox/Profiles"
                                                           isDirectory:YES];
        NSError *profileErr;
        NSArray *profileURLs = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:firefoxDir
                                          includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:&profileErr];
        if (profileURLs) {
            for (NSURL *currentProfileURL in profileURLs) {
                NSURL *removalURL = [currentProfileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"places.sqlite"
                                                                       isDirectory:NO];
                NSError *removalErr;
                if (! [fileManager removeItemAtURL:removalURL error:&removalErr]) {
                    NSLog(@"Error! %@", [removalErr localizedDescription]);
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error! %@", [profileErr localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@", [appDirErr localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Firefox API. in AppleScript editor I use *.default/places.sqlite but in objective-c don't work. An easier solution?

Comment: You could use scripting from within Cocoa, but my code does what you want and honestly isn't that hard. It's mostly error handling.